# Variável de ambiente no Github Actions

Tags: github

[imagem meu código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo8cv.jpg)

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

def send_mail():

email_address = os.getenv('EMAIL_ADDRESS') #Como fazer GitHub Actions reconhecer?
email_password = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')

contacts = ["vilsonlopes@yahoo.com.br"]
```

Olá, eu tenho um código que usa variável de ambiente como mostra a imagem acima.
Na minha máquina funciona bem, a questão é que quando subo para o repositório para executar pelo GitHub Actions eu não sei como configurar essas variáveis. Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer isso ou como é a lógica de funcionamento.